# Android (ActionBarSherlock) Is there any way to keep the same ActionBar height both in portrait and landscape?

Tags: android, landscape, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, portrait

I have been working with the ActionBar and ActionBarSherlock for the last few days, and i am having some issues when filling some information in the ActionBar.

When the application runs in portrait mode, the ActionBar looks fine, and all the data can be displayed, for example:

[image: ActionBar in portrait mode]

But when i switch the app to be displayed in landscape, some of the data is cropped:

[image: ActionBar in landscape mode]

You can notice how both the status icon and the email has been cropped due to the new height of the ActionBar.

In this case, i want to keep the same size for portrait and landscape so the app can look fine. I can't reduce the font size of the action bar title, since it may include other icons.

The way i´m putting these icons in the action bar title and subtitle is by using Html.fromHtml

Any ideas to solve this problem? I am using the ActionBarSherlock library!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

<strike>One, probably not too pretty approach, could be to override the default height values for the ActionBar in `dimens.xml`.</strike>

E.g. the default value in portrait is:

```
<dimen name="abs__action_bar_default_height">48dip</dimen>
```

And in landscape:

```
<dimen name="abs__action_bar_default_height">40dip</dimen>
```

There might be a cleaner way to do it, but I have to admit I know too little about the internals of ActionBarSherlock for that.

---

**Edit:** Come to think of it, this probably won't work when the native ActionBar is being used on ICS, since the height will then resolve to the platform value in `?android:attr/actionBarSize`. I'd recommend you wait for a better suggestion, e.g. from Jake himself.

**Second edit:**
After Jake's reply it seems like all you need to do to make it work with ActionBarSherlock on both ICS and pre-ICS devices is add the following to your app's theme:

```
<item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/some_value</item>
<item name="android:actionBarSize">@dimen/some_value</item>
```

You can then add the actual values in the relevant portrait/land resource buckets.

**Third edit** [thanks **alvarolb**]: XML Example for the style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>   
    <style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarSize">48dip</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarSize">48dip</item> 
    </style> 
</resources>
```

And in the corresponding activity, set this new style

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Styled"
```

and.. it works!

Comment: Seconded the idea to hear from Jake. This is an interesting issue. I just tested in the vanilla GTalk app on ICS, it doesn't exhibit this text cutting off issue.

Comment: Good approach, but yes, i think that it only will work for pre-ICS devices. In the GTalk app doesn't appear this issue because the title size (not subtitle) seems to be smaller than the native size. But as i commented, i cannot do this because the title also will include other (bigger) icons. I will wait for the Jake's response =)

Comment: Your follow-up is correct. Just need a non-`android`-prefixed version in the theme as well so it works on pre-ICS. Recommend you strike out the top section.

Comment: I edited your response with an example.. now it seems to work fine! thx!