# Why does the height change in landscape for actionbar sherlock?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've changed the value `abs__action_bar_default_height` in the `values-land` folder to match the value from the portrait. But when I rotate the device the actionbar is still smaller in landscape mode. What is changing its value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you testing on an ICS device by any chance? ActionBarSherlock uses the native implementation of the ActionBar on ICS, so that's why you may not see the change being reflected. The change you made will only have effect on pre-ICS devices.

That being said, in order to make it work, you can set the ActionBar height in your app's theme. If you use both `android:actionBarSize` and `actionBarSize`, it should affect any API level. Look at my [answer to an identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10890402/1029225) from about a month ago.